# Track clicks in Drupal 7 and querying with Views

Tags: 7

I'm looking to log clicks from generated URLs that are sent via email.  I need to be able to query these log entries and display the results to my users using the Views module.

What I need to track.

- Unique ID from URL clicked.
- Date and Time URL was clicked.
- Node reference (Predefined from UID)
- User reference (Predefined from UID)

Currently, my plan is to create a new content type and use references as a makeshift logging system, but this seems very bulky and expensive. Is there a way to drastically improve [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)() performance?

What would be the recommended way to accomplish a click log in Drupal?  Low overhead and Views integration are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want analytics/statistics tracking on some urls ? This has little to do with emails, or Views.

Typically you would use something like Google Analytics. There is a free open-source version with Drupal integration called [Piwik](http://www.drupal.org/project/piwik). The Piwik module lets users see analytics detail(s). You may be able to setup a "Goal" per user of the urls they should be able to see tracking for, see also the sister module [Piwik Reports](http://drupal.org/project/piwik_reports).

The builtin Statistics module can count page views ... you could try to integrate it into Views maybe if you want. The [Statistics Pro](http://drupal.org/project/statspro) module has no D7 port yet, and sounds like what you want.

Comment: Will keep an eye out for a Statistics Pro port.  I need a lighter weight solution than GA and Piwik though.  http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports looked interesting, but the API quota is way too low.